# Unable to Update Configuration Settings in Azure App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a pretty standard website running on Azure App Service.  Within that App, I have a couple of deployment slots (ex. /staging, /test).

Today, I was trying to update a configuration setting in the app and got an error message **Updating web app settings**  Failed to update web app settings: The hostname [nameofmyapp]-**staging2**.azurewebsites.net is invalid.

For a brief time, I had a slot named 'staging2' but I deleted it.  Somehow, its still sticking around and now I can't update any configuration settings anywhere.  Any ideas on how I completely kill that slot so I can update things?

Comment: Got support with Microsoft? Have you checked for remnants in Kudu?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can still see the slot or any related configuration if you navigate to the app service via https://resources.azure.com? If so, perhaps try removing extraneous configuration either via the Azure CLI or PowerShell. Though if this not a production app service, the easiest thing is probably to create a new App Service.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but only found the active/valid slots (ex: [nameofmyapp]/slot/staging) etc...